# How to recalculate coordinates of a point inside a window when the height affects the X coordinate?

Tags: math, autohotkey, aspect-ratio

I have a point inside a game that I want to click (x: 360, y: 101, at 800x600 resolution), changing the width of the window doesn't affect the coordinates of this point, however, changing the height does. The greater the height is, the more the X coordinate of this point shifts to the right. The Y coordinate also changes, but at a slower rate, not enough to make me miss the click, but help for calculating it as well would be helpful.

The code is irrelevant, but here it is

```
WinGetPos, ,,width,height,A
newX := ???            // Need help here
newY := height * 0.168 // Bad, but works
MouseMove, newX, newY
Click
```

Some extra info, the is game Path of Exile. It allows you to make the width as big as you want, which allows you to see farther. Lowering the height while keeping the same width also allows you to see farther, but it wont let you lower it below 600.

[Image for reference (800x600)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDE7r.jpg)

[Image for reference (1437x714)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Imke.jpg)

Comment: What is it that you want to click and how does it get rendered on the screen? Is it a UI element that has some fixed relative position within the window? Is it a 3D object that gets projected onto the window with a perspective transform? Can you show some examples?

Comment: @NicoSchertler It's an UI element, added two pictures to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of your target seems to depend on two things: (1) The border of your window and (2) the vertical resolution. If we focus only on the client area (i.e., the window excluding its border and titlebar) and put the origin of our coordinate system at the top left corner of this area, the position you want to click at an 800x600 resolution is `(356, 78)`. We can directly scale this point by the height ratio of the actual resolution and finally add the borders and titlebar. Hence, the final formula would be:

```
newX = borderLeft + 356 * verticalResolution / 600
newY = borderTop + titleBarHeight + 78 * verticalResolution / 600
```

Interestingly, the borders in your two screenshots are different. The 800x600 shot has a left border of 4px, whereas the other one has 1px. I assume that this is due to the screenshot and assume a left border of 4px. The top border and titlebar height are consistently 23px.

Hence, you have:

```
newX = 4 + 356 * verticalResolution / 600
newY = 23 + 78 * verticalResolution / 600
```

which gives you the location `(428, 116)` in the 1437x714 screenshot, which looks correct, except for the 3px difference due to the left border.

Comment: This made the cursor go a little bit too much to the right, missing its mark, but by changing newX from 4+356 to just 345, it works perfectly, thanks!